# How long does it take to brute force a 7 character long password taken from 16 character set

Tags: encryption, aes, brute-force

A database file is encrypted with 256bits AES and the key is the first  7 characters (from the character set 0-9, a - f, all small letter) of MD5 hash . This implies 2^28 bits (268,435,456) possible passwords. How long will take to brute force such a password?

Comment: It depends how long it takes to verify a password but https://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html indicates that you can perform about 255 million MD5 hash per second on a relatively weak CPU which, more or less, means walking through the whole keyspace in a bit over one second.

Comment: You have to factor into account hardware, as it stands your question is too broad and unlikely to allow us to provide a good answer. Are you asking about the time just out of curiosity? or do you want to know because you are assessing a specific security implementation?

Comment: @Purefan, I am writing a report on decrypting a 256BITS AES encrypted database. I don't have the facility to test out the brute forcing scenarios, however, it would help my report for knowledge and documentation purpose.

Comment: Then the most accurate answer I guess would be to figure out the logarithmic complexity, otherwise you're looking at answers like "a lot" which are not really useful

Comment: @Stephane that sounds like an answer

Comment: @Stephane - I think you've misread the benchmark chart you linked to. I don't think it's showing that it can compute 255M md5 hashes a second, but rather that it can compute an md5 hash at a rate of 255MiB/second.

Comment: @Johnny You might be right. If I check the wikipedia article, it looks like a GPU-based system can compute about 200 million hash per second (with a NVIDIA GeForce 8800 Ultra) which lands us roughly in the same place. But it's also pretty meaningless: we don't know how long it takes for a given hash to be tested since after having been hashed, it's used for AES (with unknown arrangement). That's why I don't answer the question: it cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify and expand what I said in the comment:

A GPU-based cracker can go through a LOT of MD5 hash per seconds. According to [this](http://bvernoux.free.fr/md5/index.php), one based on the (old) NVIDIA Geforce 8800 Ultra can compute about 200 million hashes per seconds. Since your keyspace is a bit above 2 millions entry large, it means that you can get through ALL of it in about one second and a half.

That doesn't, however, tell you the whole story: you're not trying to generate a collision here but you're trying to find the key used in an encryption scheme. This means that each of these hashes must then be tested. It is very possible - even likely - for this step to take much longer that simply generating a hash. Exactly how long depends on how the chosen algo is used exactly and at what stage you can decide if the key is valid or not.